# Disabling an element in Array depending on condition in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a list of participants:

```
<div class="heroWrapper">
    <div class="image hero" *ngFor="let participant of participants; index as i" [class]="i === selectedParticipant ? 'selected hero' : 'image hero'">
        <img [src]="participant.imageUrl" (click)="toggleMoves = !toggleMoves"/>
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(participant)}" class="HP">{{participant.hitPoints}}</span>
        <span class="namePlayer" *ngIf="isHero(participant)">{{getPlayerName(participant)}}</span>
        <span class="nameHero">{{participant.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a next and previous button:

```
next() {
    if (this.selectedParticipant != this.participants.length - 1) {
        ++this.selectedParticipant;
    } else {
        this.selectedParticipant = 0;
    }

    this.toggleMove();
}

previous() {
    if (this.selectedParticipant != 0) {
        --this.selectedParticipant;
    } else {
        this.selectedParticipant = this.participants.length - 1;
    }

    this.toggleMove();
}
```

The selectedParticipant is the index of the element in the array.
Now, when the participants HP is 0, I would like them to be disabled, meaning that they would be skipped by the next and previous method. And when they're disabled, i'd like them to be grayed out.

I tried adding

```
if (this.participants[selectedParticipant].hitPoints = 0) {
    ++selectedParticipant;
    if (this.selectedParticipant != this.participants.length - 1) {
        ++this.selectedParticipant;
    } else {
        this.selectedParticipant = 0;
    }
}
```

I have to use the same code twice because it has to be checked each team. But for some reason, this set the participants hitPoints to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement needs to have **==** instead of single **=**, which is why the hp of the particpants gets set to 0

**==** is a compare operator

**=** is an assignment operator

```
next() {
    if(this.participants[selectedParticipant].hitPoints == 0) {
       ++this.selectedParticipant;
       if (this.selectedParticipant > this.participants.length - 1) {
           this.selectedParticipant = 0;
       }

       this.toggleMove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here assignment has taken place instead of a comparison.

Make it a practice to write constants on the left side so that assignment wont occur instead of a comparison.

eg.

```
if (0 == this.participants[selectedParticipant].hitPoints) { 
}



if (0 = this.participants[selectedParticipant].hitPoints) {
} // it would break the execution and give an error because constants cant be assigned a value and so you find out the error easily.
```